# Block multiple UI threads for a dialog in WPF

Tags: wpf, multithreading, dialog

In the moment, I have a problem with multiple UI threads in WPF.

I have a third party component, which I need to use in a project. Unfortunately, every function of the component needs to be executed in the UI thread. The component itself has some long-term operations. For these operations, I want to show a Dialog that shows the progress of the operation. Additionally it should also be possible to cancel this operation. Since the long-term action of the component needs to be executed in the UI thread, the update of the progress bar is not very nice.

To avoid this problem I have put the dialog window in a separated UI thread. Now the progress is displayed as expected and very smoothly. However, now the dialog do not behave as a dialog. Since it is hosted in, a separate UI Thread It only blocks the User Interaction for this UI Thread and not for the main UI thread.  Nevertheless, I want the dialog to block the main Window.

It would be possible to use Mousehoocks to achieve something like this. However, I want to know if it is possible to achieve this with WPF, C# functionality.

Therefore, I hope that anyone can help me with this problem.

Comment: Instead of putting the entire dialog in a separate thread, why not create a separate "UI" thread just for the lengthy operations. Then, in your progress callbacks, marshal back to the main UI thread. You should also wrap all this up in a service to enforce the required semantics.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/cdb9127e-9ab5-438f-85f2-221fa3ffbce1

Comment: @ Kent Boogaart
Thanks for the answer but we want to combine certain controls from the single-threaded third-party component (that work with the inner logic of the third-party component) into our own window, so opening a separate UI thread for those is not practicable, I think.

Comment: @ YK1
Thanks, the problem described in the thread seems to be the same as our. Minimizing the main application while showing the progress is not desired though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have found an interesting Article that helped us to solve the problem.

[Host Visual](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual.aspx)